# Result will display two times in blade file in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I am creating task in which i want to display notification based on notification_status & order_status .
From controller only three record is obtained but in blade file the loop repeat, two record two times.
As expected output, i want to display only first three record but it repeat again second & third record. How can remove this confusion?

controller:

```
public function get_notification()
    {
        $userId=Session::get('userid');
       $data = DB::select('Select orders.product_id,subcategory.image,GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory.name_of_subcategory) as subcategory,orders.grand_total,orders.deliver_date,orders.order_status,orders.notification_status,orders.orders_id,orders.payment_status,orders.orders_date from orders inner join product_details on FIND_IN_SET(product_details.product_id,orders.product_id) > 0 inner join subcategory on product_details.sub_id=subcategory.sub_id where orders.user_id=? GROUP BY orders.product_id,orders.deliver_date,orders.order_status,orders.orders_id,orders.notification_status,orders.orders_date,orders.payment_status,orders.orders_subtotal,subcategory.image,orders.grand_total',[$userId]);
        return view('notification')->with('data',$data);
    }
```

blade:

```
@foreach($data as $notification)


                    <div class="card-body noti-card" id="noti-card">
                        <div class="row mt-2">


                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div>

                                    <span><img src="{{asset('images/subcategory/'.$notification->image)}}" class="img-fluid" height="100" width="100"></span><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div>
                                    <span>
                                        <?php
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 1 && $notification->order_status ==1){
                                                echo "<b>Order Placed</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your order for ".$notification->subcategory." with order ID ODI".$notification->orders_id." amounting to Rs.".$notification->grand_total." has been received.";
                                            }
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 2 && $notification->order_status == 2)
                                            {
                                                echo "<b>Order Cancelled</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your order for".$notification->subcategory." with order ID ODI".$notification->orders_id." is successfully cancelled.";
                                            }
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 3 && $notification->order_status == 3)
                                            {
                                                echo "<b>Product Packed</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your package containing ".$notification->subcategory." has been packed by seller and will be shipped soon.";
                                            }
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 4 && $notification->order_status == 4)
                                            {
                                                echo "<b>Product Shipped</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your package containing ".$notification->subcategory." has been shipped by seller and will be delivered soon.";
                                            }
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 5 && $notification->order_status == 5){
                                                echo "<b>Out for Delivery</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your package containing ".$notification->subcategory." from Aarch Ayurved will be delivered today";
                                            }
                                            if($notification->notification_status == 6 && $notification->order_status == 6){
                                                echo "<b>Product Delivered</b><br>";
                                                echo "Your package containing ".$notification->subcategory." has been delivered. Thanks for shopping!";
                                            }

                                        ?>
                                    </span>

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="noti-date"><?php
                                    $timestamp = strtotime("$notification->orders_date");
                                    $formattedDate = date('F d, Y', $timestamp);
                                    echo $formattedDate;
                                    ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @endsection

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadlink(){
            $('#noti-card').load('/notification #noti-card');
            console.log('TESTING!!!!');
        }
        loadlink();
        setInterval(function(){
            loadlink()
        }, 1000);

    </script>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The duplication is most likely coming from the query. Can youuse the Laravel helper methods `dump()` or `dd()` the results right after running the query to confirm? e.g. `dd($data)` immediately after the query would allow you to see the results the query returns and verify if they match expectations or not.

I believe the issue might be in the join to product_details. What is the intent of using `FIND_IN_SET()`?

The query would be much easier to read and understand if it where broken onto multiple lines. It might be easier to troubleshoot if you switch to using query builder, which would look something like this:

```
$data = DB::table('orders')
    ->select([
        'orders.deliver_date',
        'orders.grand_total',
        'orders.notification_status',
        'orders.order_status',
        'orders.orders_date',
        'orders.orders_date',
        'orders.orders_id',
        'orders.payment_status',
        'orders.product_id',
        'subcategory.image',
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory.name_of_subcategory) as subcategory'),
    ])
    ->join('product_details', 'orders.product_id', '=', 'product_details.product_id')
    ->join('subcategory', 'product_details.sub_id', '=', 'subcategory.sub_id')
    ->where('orders.user_id', '=', $userId)
    ->groupBy(
        'orders.product_id',
        'orders.deliver_date',
        'orders.order_status',
        'orders.orders_id',
        'orders.notification_status',
        'orders.orders_date',
        'orders.payment_status',
        'orders.orders_subtotal',
        'subcategory.image',
        'orders.grand_total'
    )
    ->get();
```